# Custom Query Dynamic Data Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use a Dynamic Data Application and having issues with customizing a query. Everything scaffolds wonderfully, however, I want to be able color code the main Parent table when a Child Objects Property is a certain value. Normally I would just iterate over the data using LINQ however, all the information I've researched always filters and color codes items in the grid based on the Parent level data. Any ideas on how to do this on Child Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ItemDataBound event of the *child* control, if the condition is met, you can walk up the control hierarchy recursively until you reach the row/item of the parent grid. Once you get to the row/item, you can set the color to whatever you need.

Comment: Actually I was talking about going th other direction down the data object tree into the child to verify a property value.

Comment: That makes it even easier. Recursively drill down the control hierarchy.

Comment: Here is a link which will give you an idea of what you need to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070172/iterate-through-textboxes-in-vb-web-app/7070355#7070355